# Деепричастный оборот как одно из однородных обстоятельств

Tags: синтаксис

*Шекспир, «Гамлет», перевод Пастернака, акт третий, сцена вторая, ремарка:*

> Возвращается королева, видит, что король мертв, и жестами выражает отчаяние. **Снова входит отравитель с двумя или тремя похоронными служителям и, давая понять, что разделяет ее горе.** Труп уносят.

Каков верный синтаксический разбор выделенного предложения? Я в этом могу видеть только два однородных обстоятельства: «с двумя или тремя похоронными служителям» и «давая понять, что разделяет ее горе». Такое употребление допустимо?

Действительно ли должен в этом случае обособляться такой деепричастный оборот?

Comment: Я вижу два варианта корректного перевода: [Вариант 1](https://books.google.by/books?id=Qc_MAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=%22%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82+%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%22&source=bl&ots=66eeea3t_M&sig=qiTNryVMY0L0HWXmB08nSdHCqvY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ySW2VLSlOYa5ggT5uYPICA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) - нет непонятного союза "и".

Comment: И [Вариант 2](http://www.nemerovsky.com/anna/plays-2/hamletdirbyshakespeare/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9) - глагол вместо деепричастия.

Comment: Это вполне ясно, но как же вариант Пастернака? Он ошибочен?

Comment: Мне кажется, что ошибочен - лишний пробел между "служителям" и "и". Возможно, некорректно распознан\напечатан текст.

Comment: Да, это верно, опубликуйте это как ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В данном предложении, вероятно, некорректно распознан или перепечатан текст, что привело к появлению пробела между словами *служителям* и *и*. Вот [корректный вариант перевода](https://books.google.by/books?id=Qc_MAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT134&lpg=PT134&dq=%22%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D1%81%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%22&source=bl&ots=66eeea3t_M&sig=qiTNryVMY0L0HWXmB08nSdHCqvY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ySW2VLSlOYa5ggT5uYPICA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Снова входит отравитель с двумя или тремя похоронными **служителями**, **давая** **понять**,что разделяет ее горе.